# Outlook Addin sometimes fails to load in browser

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Outlook Add-in is sometimes failing to load in browsers. It is not even hitting the app end point url configured in manifest file.

Please check the screenshot of error logged in developer tools.
[image]

This plugin is not published to Office Store. User will manually configure manifest file in his account.

added office365.com in AppDomain section. still it is complaining the same.

AppDomain section from manifest file :

```
<AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>xyz.myDomain.us</AppDomain>         
        <AppDomain>r4.res.office365.com</AppDomain>
        <AppDomain>outlook.office.com</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
```

Error is coming even before hitting my app endpoint url.

Now i am seeing this issue in chrome. It was working fine before. I suspect something wrong with cache. It stopped working after some using some period.

**IMP: I tried installing some other apps. They are also failing to load in my account. I doubt this issue is not specific to my application.**

Screenshot with boomerang app which is failing to load :
[image]

**NOTE: After clearing browser history, app is loading. How it is dependent on history?**

Comment: Is the add-in run from VS or it's already on server / store ? can you give us more details . thx .

Comment: It is js plugin. not published to app store. user manually upload manifest file and runs the app with endpoint hitting our servers

Comment: ok ,in which browser it's work and which no ? when you copy the address you redirect to your add-in to browser it's work good?

Comment: Now i am seeing this issue in chrome. It was working fine before. I suspect something wrong with cache. It stopped working after some using some period.

Comment: Are you still facing issues with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're manifest file is invalid, in fact it seems to have multiple manifests in it. Take a look at line [23](https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/da43b8c8a7507de3680fa3f28ba206eb#file-manifest-xml-L23)-[25](https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/da43b8c8a7507de3680fa3f28ba206eb#file-manifest-xml-L25):

```xml
 <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://sf.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:ce44715c-8c4e-446b-879c-ea9ebe0f09c8-->
<OfficeApp
```

You have the beginning of a correct manifest but it stops at line 23 and then restarts an entirely new manifest. This manifest runs until line [289](https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/da43b8c8a7507de3680fa3f28ba206eb#file-manifest-xml-L289). It looks like a manifest was simply pasted into another manifest.

I've forked and updated the [Gist of your manifest](https://gist.github.com/mlafleur/958a873e88c92abd6f7c3a05c33ec958).

Comment: i modified the app domain section. but still same error. update question with manifest appdomain section. please check

Comment: You're missing the `https://` prefix on those domains. You also shouldn't need to add the `Office` domains. Can you provide your manifest as well?

Comment: please check my manifest file here : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/da43b8c8a7507de3680fa3f28ba206eb